# php loading before $.post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a main page we'll call it page A. I have a navigation menu on page A that executes $.post from `jQuery` when an item is clicked. Then when it finishes it hides a few div's and shows one.

Well the div it shows has a `PHP` file inflating the content. This is the same `PHP` file it sends the $.post to and this file is included on page A.

So when the page loads the nav and hidden divs it also loads the `PHP` file *without* the $.post data.

Here is some code and I'll explain further

**jQuery**

```
$('#projects').click(function (e) {
    $.trim(account_id); 
    $.post('core/functions/projects.php', { 
        account_id: account_id                    
    })
    .done(function(data) {      
        $('#scd').hide();
        $('#icd').hide();       
        $('#pcd').fadeIn(1000);     
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    }); 

});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

if(empty($_POST) === false) {

    $account_id = $_POST['account_id'];

    try {
        $query_projectInfo = $db->prepare("
            SELECT  projects.account_id,
                    projects.project_name,                  
                    .... //more code, not relevant 
            FROM projects
            WHERE account_id = ?                        
        "); 

        $query_projectInfo->bindValue(1, $account_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_projectInfo->execute();
        $count = $query_projectInfo->rowCount();

        if ($count > 0) {
            echo "<table class='contentTable'>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Job #" . "</th>";
            echo "<th class='content_th'>" . "Project Name" . "</th>";
            ... //more code, not relevant            
            while ($row = $query_projectInfo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {                
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . "<a href='#'>" . $row['account_id'] . "</a>" . "</td>";
                echo "<td class='content_td'>" . $row['project_name'] . "</td>";
                .... //more code, not relevant                  
            }
            echo "</table>";            
        }       
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
} else {
    echo 'could not load projects table';
}
?>
```

Now all I ever see when I click #project on the nav menu is the `else` statement of 'could not load projects table'. I believe this is because the `PHP` file is loaded before the nav item is ever clicked. It seems like when I click the item and send the post it's like the `PHP` page says "i already loaded buddy, I'm not doing that again".

So my question is, how would I make the `PHP` file wait to load? I thought that `if else` condition would do it, obviously I was wrong.

P.S. If I give the $account_id variable a value rather than wait for post the div inflates with the table and all the info. So the `PHP` file is operational. It just doesn't wait for that $.post

Comment: `empty($_POST) === false` to `isset($_POST)`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy god, I really am struggling today. I wish i could take the day off. Thanks. Post that as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This check will never fire. `empty($_POST) === false`

If you're simply wanting to check if `$_POST` has data, just use `isset($_POST)`

Comment: Weird. I consider myself a senior php dev (been employed on it for years), and yet it looks like I'm about to learn some new glitch in php I haven't come across before. Why is `empty($_POST)` not false if it contains the `account_id` entry as per the OP? I'm guessing some strange superglobal behaviour?

Comment: ugh, another error, time for a new question... i hate today =)