# Want to use AJAX to refresh content after clicking submit button

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Currently I have a database filled with collectible cards. I'm using php to display the cards from my database and this is working fine. The output includes a button to delete that specific card. The AJAX works when clicked but the card is not removed.

I have index.php which is just a html page with:

```
<?php include 'showallcards.php';?>
```

Showallcards.php:

```
        <?php
require_once 'connectdb.php';

$serielijst = "SELECT naam, jaar FROM series ORDER BY jaar ASC";
$serieresult = $conn->query($serielijst);
while($row = $serieresult->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo '<div class="serie" id="' . $row["naam"] . '">';
    echo "<h2>" . $row["naam"]. " </h2> " . $row["jaar"]. "<br />";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cards WHERE serie = '". $row["naam"] . "' ORDER BY cardname ASC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        echo '<ul id="cardsul">';
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<li class="card" id="' . $row["id"] . '"><a href="'. $row["img"] .'"><img src="'. $row["img"] .'"/></a>';
            echo 'Card<br/><h4>' .$row["cardname"] . '</h4>Type<h4>' . $row["cardtype"] . ' - ' . $row["cardsubtype"]. '</h4></br>Serie<h4>' . $row["serie"]. '</h4>Rarity<h4>' . $row["rarity"]. '</h4>Manacost<h4>' . $row["manacost"].  '</h4>Color<h4>' . $row["color"]. '</h4>Artist<h4>' . $row["artist"]. '</h4>Power / Toughness<h4>' . $row["power"] . ' / ' . $row["toughness"] . '<br/>';
            echo '<div class="status" id="wanted">' . $row["want"] . '</div>';
            echo '<div class="status" id="favorited">' . $row["favorite"] . '</div>';
            echo '<div class="status" id="collectioned">' . $row["incollection"] . '</div>';
            echo '<div class="status" id="del_wrapper"><button id="'.$row['id'].'">Delete</button></div>';
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul><div class="clear"></div>';
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

In this script I fetch all the cards and display them. Also there is included a button to delete a specific card when pressed.

The php file for deleteing is delete_card.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['del_id'])) {
    $del_id = $_POST['del_id'];
    $del_sql="DELETE FROM cards WHERE id='$del_id'";
    $del_result = $conn->query($del_sql);
}
?>
```

I've tested if the file is loaded by echoing a simple text.

With the help of the ajax code from one of the commentors I've got this far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var card_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/goblins/delete_card.php", 
            method: "POST",
            data: {del_id: card_id},
            success: function(result){
             $('li[id="' + card_id + '"]').fadeOut();
        }});
    });
});
```

This loads the php file because success is working. The card is faded out but when I reload the page the card returns and is not deleted from the database. I figure it's because `if (isset($_POST['del_id']))` is not returning true yet.
Who can help me out? Much apreciated!

Raoul

Comment: Why not set the id attribute of the card to the id in the database. When you delete it, upon returning the result with ajax, hide the deleted card by targetting the id of the card div or whatever, and using the hide()  method in JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the row id as an attribute of each `<li>` element in your while loop:

```
echo '<li id="'$row[id]'"class="card"><a href="'. $row["img"] .'"><img src="'. $row["img"] .'"/></a>';
        echo 'Card<br/><h4>' .$row["cardname"] . '</h4>Type<h4>' . $row["cardtype"] . ' - ' . $row["cardsubtype"]. '</h4></br>Serie<h4>' . $row["serie"]. '</h4>Rarity<h4>' . $row["rarity"]. '</h4>Manacost<h4>' . $row["manacost"].  '</h4>Color<h4>' . $row["color"]. '</h4>Artist<h4>' . $row["artist"]. '</h4>Power / Toughness<h4>' . $row["power"] . ' / ' . $row["toughness"] . '<br/>';
        echo '<div class="status" id="wanted">' . $row["want"] . '</div>';
        echo '<div class="status" id="favorited">' . $row["favorite"] . '</div>';
        echo '<div class="status" id="collectioned">' . $row["incollection"] . '</div>';
        echo '<div class="status del_wrapper" id="' . $row["id"] . '"><button id="'.$row['id'].'">Delete</button></div>';
        echo '</li>';
```

Then put your delete script in a separate php file and call it with AJAX when deleting a card:

```
// DELETE SCRIPT (in separate file delete.php)
if (isset($_POST['del_id'])) {
    $del_id = $_POST['del_id'];
    $del_sql="DELETE FROM cards WHERE id='$del_id'";
    $del_result = $conn->query($del_sql);
    echo $del_result;
}
```

Then on delete click, call the delete.php script with AJAX and on success, hide the li element for that card (remember to include JQuery if you haven't already):

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var card_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "delete.php",
        method: "POST",
        data:{'del_id':card_id},
        success: function() {
            $('li[id="' + card_id + '"]').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've put the delete sccript in a separate script and changed the form into the button.
When I click the delete button unfortunatly nothing happens yet. In firefox debug console i get this: SyntaxError: missing } after property list on the line of dataType

Comment: Hi again, try it now, I made a few adjustments to the way the data is passed in within the ajax method.

Comment: Thanks again for helping. I have got the ajax working but the php if isset post is not running true yet. I updated my post to reflect the changes i made

Comment: Can you console.log(card_id); in the JavaScript after it is initialised? If that isn't holding the ID of the card, it won't be passing it to the delete PHP script correctly.

Comment: I've just noticed, you have an error in your delete_card.php. You are checking if $_POST['del_id'] is set, but then assigning $_POST['card_id'] inside the IF statement. Match the $_POST variable names and try again.

Comment: I used <script>console.log(card_id);</script> at the bottom of my index.php. Is that the correct way? It returns `ReferenceError: card_id is not defined` In the console. So I guess it's not holding the value

Comment: use the consode.log(card_id); right after var card_id = $(this).attr('id');

Comment: Also, inspect the button element and see what the ID value is, ensure it is being set in the markup. Is the column name "id" present in your table? I assumed that is what you called your primary id column.

Comment: The Id is set, every instance of the button has the id of the card.
When i place the console.log just beneath the var card_id I get nothing in my console.
Edit: setting both post values to either card_id or del_id gave no change.
ID is the first column in my table and is set as primary key

Comment: inside the onclick, type alert($(this).attr('id')); See what value is alerted.

Comment: Hang on, replace <button id="'.$row['id'].'" />Delete</button> with <button id="'.$row['id'].'" >Delete</button>

Comment: I have this in my js: `var card_id = $(this).attr('id');
  alert($(this).attr('id'));`
It shows the id in a popup. So I guess it's saving the id in the var.
I also changed the / in button

Comment: Yes! I found the answer here: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911472/jquery-ajax-post-to-php-file-not-working`

my ajax now looks like this:
`data:{'card_id':card_id},;`

Answer (score 0):

If you have to reload page after successful ajax request, you can use `location.reload();`  on success function like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  location.reload();
});
```